# Add Loop in jquery Live

Tags: jquery

I have a little question.

I am having a form field repeating in all rows which is coupled with a LIVE event to trigger a jQuery function.

Can I add an iteration here somehow? repetitive code is really not the thing I want...

```
 $("#exampassed1").autocomplete({
  source: "exams.php",
  minLength: 2
 });

 $("#exampassed2").live('focus', function() {

  $("#exampassed2").autocomplete({
  source: "exams.php",
  minLength: 2
  });

 });

 $("#exampassed3").live('focus', function() {

  $("#exampassed3").autocomplete({
  source: "exams.php",
  minLength: 2
  });

 });

 $("#exampassed4").live('focus', function() {

  $("#exampassed4").autocomplete({
  source: "exams.php",
  minLength: 2
  });

 });

 $("#exampassed5").live('focus', function() {

  $("#exampassed5").autocomplete({
  source: "exams.php",
  minLength: 2
  });

 });

 $("#exampassed6").live('focus', function() {

  $("#exampassed6").autocomplete({
  source: "exams.php",
  minLength: 2
  });

 });

 $("#exampassed7").live('focus', function() {

  $("#exampassed7").autocomplete({
  source: "exams.php",
  minLength: 2
  });

 });

 $("#exampassed8").live('focus', function() {

  $("#exampassed8").autocomplete({
  source: "exams.php",
  minLength: 2
  });

 });

 $("#exampassed9").live('focus', function() {

  $("#exampassed9").autocomplete({
  source: "exams.php",
  minLength: 2
  });

 });

 $("#exampassed10").live('focus', function() {

  $("#exampassed10").autocomplete({
  source: "exams.php",
  minLength: 2
  });

 });
```

I was thinking of something like this for the elements after the first

```
 $("#exampassed2", "#exampassed3").live('focus', function() {

  $("#exampassed2").autocomplete({
  source: "exams.php",
  minLength: 2
  });

 });
```

or

```
 $($("#exampassed2"), $("#exampassed3")).live('focus', function() {

  $("#exampassed2").autocomplete({
  source: "exams.php",
  minLength: 2
  });

 });
```

or

```
 $("#exampassed2"), $("#exampassed3").live('focus', function() {

  $("#exampassed2").autocomplete({
  source: "exams.php",
  minLength: 2
  });

 });
```

none works perfectly... any clues anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a class instead of iterated ids

```
$(".exampassed:first").autocomplete({
  source: "exams.php",
  minLength: 2
});
$(".exampassed").live('focus',function(){
  $(this).autocomplete({
    source: "exams.php",
    minLength: 2
  });
})
```

Comment: for the record it's `$("#exampassed2, #exampassed3").live(...`

Comment: works like a charm for the autocomplete albeit does not work for the datepicker :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the comma inside the quotes in order to select multiple objects, like this:

```
$("#exampassed2, #exampassed3").live('focus', function() {

  $(this).autocomplete({
  source: "exams.php",
  minLength: 2
  });

 });
```

You do not need to reselect the jquery object inside the live function, as the $(this) selector will reference the current object.

More information on Multiple Selectors can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: thanks for the reply dustin - can we use this for the datepicker as well?

Comment: I have never used the datepicker, so I couldn't tell you for sure. I don't see why you couldn't, though.

Comment: Hello Dustin - actually the Datepicker has a different working which however got improved in jquery 1.4.4 - I solved it. Thanks a lot for your help. It made my 300 line script to be compressed into 65 lines. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Dustin and Henry for the replies.

I not only solved this error with your help but found a solution for how to implement this same trick on the DatePicker as well

here it is below

```
    $(".oyekidda:first").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '1900:2050',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
});

$(".oyekidda").live('click',function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker({
        showOn: 'focus',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '1900:2050',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    }).focus();
})
```

Cheers!